# Make % working on "begin" or "end" in a SQL block

Tags: vim

In TSQL, we are using BEGIN  END to embrace a block instead of {}.  We can use % to go the beginning or ending of a block if using {}, but I want to go the beginning or ending of a block even if using BEGIN, END, how could that be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the shipped matchit plugin is for! :)

```
:set filetype=sql
:runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

Afterwards I could use <kbd>%</kbd> on `begin`/`end`, too.

See `:help sql-matchit` and `:echo b:match_words` (after you set the filetype to *sql*) to get a list of all word pairs % is working on.

Thus, assuming `b:match_words` woudn't include `begin`/`end` by default, you would add a new pair like this:

```
:let b:match_words .= ',\<begin\>:\<end\>'
```